# Can't increment value of a Page variable in Asp.net on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever i click on the Button1 repeatedly then text in the Literal1 is not incremented. Can you please tell me reason?

Expected: value show in text field increment after every button click.

Current result: value always shows 1.

```
public partial class d1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
int c;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        c = 1;
        Literal1.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c=c+1;
    Literal1.Text = c.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Also, `c` isn't a "global variable."  It's a private instance variable on the class `d1`.

Comment: @davisoa: No; that will not work well.

Comment: Given the lack of question, I couldn't resist suggesting the simple solution

Comment: The author has yet to define a question. Making `c` static won't solve his problem, because there is non yet defined.

Comment: @davisoa The lack of a question should encourage you to *not* try to suggest solutions, but rather figure out what the question is. Proposing solutions to a problem you don't understand helps no one, and often is even harmful.

Comment: Investigate ASP.NET State Management: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/30/state-management/

Comment: @Servy well said - I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @AdityaKumar How *should* it work?  Explain several examples of how this page should function.  Should it go up when anyone presses the button?  Should it indicate the number of times that one user has pressed the button?  Should it indicate the number of times they've pressed the button since they last did a non-postback request?

Comment: @David reopening as you have very good explanation in comment to be posted as answer.

Comment: The problem is that you're incrementing an *instance* field. A *new instance* of your `Page` subclass is created for **every** page request (GET, POST, whatever). Changes made to an instance field only last for the duration of the request. You could use a *static* field, but you'll need to synchronize access to it, but then there is only a single value across all users of the page. More appropriately, you probably want to use session state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That explains the current behavior, but as it's unclear what the desired behavior is the question still isn't answerable.

Comment: Question may be stupid for people who disliked it. But i am a beginner. try to help. thanks for people who answered me

Comment: @AdityaKumar The problem with this question has nothing to do with it's skill level.  The problem is that you have not clearly described your requirements, so people *can't* help you even if they wanted to.  When you have more clearly explained what your program needs to do, even if it's a simple task, and also assuming you've done some basic research into the task to ensure that the solution to your problem isn't easily accessible to you, then you'll find you questions will be received much better.

Comment: It's not a stupid question.  It's poorly asked and researched.

Comment: I have english problem too thats why not able to explain that much. sorry

Comment: @Servy - I think you trying to be too helpful :). Stateless web server code is huge shift from beginners stateful console/WinForm samples, so it is quite reasonable to not understand the difference between persistent Form and and recreated-on-every-request Page classes... So I think the question is reasonable for SO as it stands now (and gives good info for original poster). It even includes somewhat "what I want to do" in form of "counter not incremented on multiple postbacks...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's entirely reasonable to not understand the stateless web system.  It's not understandable to refuse to explain what you would like your code to do, especially after being asked to clarify that exact point.  He doesn't need to know anything about ASP, state in a web environment, etc. to explain what he wants the program to do in response to a few different example situations.

Comment: @Servy - agree, but it is hardest part - to know how to ask good questions. Anyway, I've changed the question to match the answer. I think should be fine now.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov See my first comment.  It's still unclear.  I have my guess, but there is still conflicting evidence, so using it in an answer wouldn't be appropriate.  The OP simply needs to clarify which of the many possible interpretations is what he wants.  He's refused to do so, and as a result this is a very poor quality question.  If he would answer my first set of questions, then the question may be able to be edited into passable shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `c` is an *instance* variable on that class. And each post-back to the server creates a new instance of the class. So `c` is being initialized to `0` on each post-back. If you want `c` to persist outside of a single instance of that class, you need to store it somewhere. Session, application, a database, etc.  (Specifically where depends on under what circumstances the value of `c` should persist.  I'm guessing this is just test code to get a feel for the functionality, so you might try all of the above and see how they differ.)

For a *lot* more information on this, you'll want to read up on the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Essentially, "global" doesn't describe `c` very accurately as a variable.  It's scope is very limited to only that class, and more specifically only to any one instance of that class.